# How to create a detached process in java on linux

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I am currently writing a java program that needs to run the linux `rpm` command and part of the `rpm` install stops the jvm that the `rpm` command was launched from.

I have tried to run process builder with the `nohup` and `&` then as well to detach the process to no avail as well as try `Runtime.exec()` with no success also using `nohup` and `&` the code I have done to launch the process is posted below.

They always exit and give an error saying the process that was doing the update has exited so the `rpm` command has failed.

Why are these calls to spawn a detached process failing and exiting when the jvm exits?

```
public static void noWaitrunProcess(String commands[], String commandInputText) 
        throws InterruptedException {
    ProcessInfo processInfo = new ProcessInfo();
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        if(commandInputText != null){
            outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            writer.write(commandInputText);
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        processInfo.procOutput = "error running process";
    } finally {
        if(writer != null)
        {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently getting this error when the install is attemped

```
D:   install: waitpid(5668) rc 5668 status f secs 0.099
error: %pre(a[[-3.0-9.160513095338.i686) scriptlet failed, signal 15
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping app-3.0-9.160513095338
```

Comment: works for me. e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nohup xterm");` same result via `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @zapl hmmm if it doesnt work this time then I will post my code I have.

Comment: @zapl posting the code now

Comment: Processes are naturally detached. That's their default state, by virtue of being separate processes. You don't have to do extra work to make them backgrounded.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes that is also true. However, the process created by the process builder in the jvm always exits when the jvm exits. I want the process to stick around after the jvm exits or at least figure out some way to debug what is happening since there is no rpm log or anything i know of to look at on RHEL all i know is the `rpm` didn't update so the process failed

Comment: Why is the JVM exiting? What RPM command are you running?

Comment: @JohnKugelman the jvm is exiting because it is a daemon java program that is being updated from within its self. So part of the rpm script is to stop the daemon so update can be done, thus the jvm exits since was stopped by rpm. also am running `rpm -Uvh`

Comment: could be http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159038 - basically  implicitly closing of the outputstream (which shouldn't happen with nohup because it redirect that stream)

Comment: How does the RPM script stop the daemon? What kill command does it use? It may be overly aggressive and be killing more than just the java process.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I believe it uses the regular kill command with the pid, since kill -9 would have bad consequences so it sends a `SIG_TERM`.

Comment: @zapl that seems to be signal 13, I am getting a signal 15

Comment: @JohnKugelman I relooked at how the daemon is killed and a `signal 1` is actually passed am testing out now with `signal 15`

Comment: Is this from a daemon running under systemd?

Comment: @derobert yes well its started using upstart but you get the jist it sounds like

Comment: @jgr208 Ah... If it were systemd, that'd be systemd's control-group based process control, and I'd suggest the workaround is to create a separate systemd unit to run the upgrade. But not sure about upstart.

Comment: @derobert that could be an idea. ill have to do some research but starts me off on the right direction